# Sum of prime numbers below 500

Tags: c

I made the following code:

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<stdbool.h>
  3
  4 bool c[500];
  5 void main()
  6 {
  7  int i,n=1,j;
  8  for (i=2; i<500; i++)
  9  {
 10         if (!c[i])
 11         {
 12                 printf("%d is the prime number %d\n", i,n);
 13                 n++;
 14                 j=2;
 15                 while (j*i<500)
 16                 {
 17                         c[j*i]=1;
 18                         j++;
 19                 }
 20         }
 21  }
 22 }
```

It displays the prime numbers below 500; now, how can I also make the program display the sum of all those numbers(all the prime numbers below 500) in just a few lines?thanks for your help, I'm new to C

Comment: Make a variable to hold the sum of primes. Initialize it to zero. When you find a new prime, add it to the sum. Print it after you finish your loop.

Comment: |Can you show me how? I have a general idea on how to do that but don't know where to put the variable, it took me ages just to finish this code.

Comment: You wrote that code yourself, but you don't know how to make the tiniest modification to it? OK.

Comment: I was setting a global variable instead of one inside the function, so it didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. At the start, set a variable `sum` to zero.
2. Then, every time you currently output a prime number, add it to `sum` as well.
3. Then, when you're finished, output `sum`.

---

So, assuming your code works otherwise, you would change, for point 1 above:

```
int i,n=1,j;
```

into:

```
int i,n=1,j,sum=0;
```

---

Point 2 involves changing:

```
printf("%d is the prime number %d\n", i,n);
```

into:

```
printf("%d is the prime number %d\n", i,n);
sum += i;
```

---

And, finally, point 3 can be enacted by placing:

```
printf("Sum of all those primes is %d\n", sum);
```

before the final closing brace.

---

The changes to your code, including commenting and more appropriate variable names in an effort to make readable, would be something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Find/sum all primes less than this number.

#define LIMIT 500

// Flag indicating a number is non-prime, initialised to zeros.

bool isComposite[LIMIT];

void main (void) {
    int num, mult;
    int count = 1, sum = 0;

    // Check every number for primeness.

    for (num = 2; num < LIMIT; num++) {
        // Ignore if composite.

        if (!isComposite[num]) {
            // Print prime, add to sum.

            printf ("%d is the prime number %d\n", num, count++);
            sum += num;

            // Mark all multiples of it as composite.

            for (mult = num * 2; mult < LIMIT; mult += num) {
                isComposite[mult] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Now just output the sum.

    printf ("The sum of those primes is %d\n", sum);
}
```

Don't copy that if it's classwork, you'll probably get found out. I include it just to show you how much more readable code can be if you follow a few simple rules, some of which are below:

- Use comments copiously, generally to describe *what* you're doing, not *how.*
- Use decent variable names.
- Try to avoid 'magic' constants like `500`.
- Minimise vertical space taken as long as it doesn't affect readability (it's usually better to see as much code on the screen as possible).

Comment: thans a lot, really :)

Answer (score 2):

Add Extra variable `sum`

Like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

   bool c[500];
   int main()
   {
    int i,n=1,j,sum=0;
    for (i=2; i<500; i++)
    {
          if (!c[i])
          {
                printf("%d is the prime number %d\n", i,n);
                sum+=i;
                  n++;
                 j=2;
                  while (j*i<500)
                 {
                          c[j*i]=1;
                         j++;
                  }
          }
   }
   printf("Sum is %d",sum);
 }
```

Comment: pinch !! :P please pinch me back also :P

Answer (score 1):

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<stdbool.h>
  3
  4 bool c[500];
  5 void main()
  6 {
  7  int i,n=1,j; int sum = 0;
  8  for (i=2; i<500; i++)
  9  {
 10         if (!c[i])
 11         {
 12                 printf("%d is the prime number %d\n", i,n);
 13                 sum += i; n++;
 14                 j=2;
 15                 while (j*i<500)
 16                 {
 17                         c[j*i]=1;
 18                         j++;
 19                 }
 20         }
 21  } printf("sum: %d", sum);
 22 }
```

Comment: This doesn't actually compile.

Comment: sorry.. somehow the letter 't' from the word int got removed... fixed